# ThreeJS Rotation Animation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a cube in ThreeJS and I would like to rotate it 90 degrees clockwise every time I press a button. I think I have the basic gist of it: create a Three.Animation instance, bind it to the cube, and then have the animation begin every time I press the correct button. However, I'm having a difficult time understanding ThreeJS's API, because it doesn't seem to contain any examples for its methods.

This is THREE.js's Animation constructor: ( root, data, interpolationType, JITCompile ) I don't understand what goes into the fields. I'm guessing root would be where I put my cube, but what about the rest?

Also can I just call `animation.play()` to cause the animation whenever I want? And how does the animationHandler work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think for for rotating an object 90 degrees clockwise, using the TWEEN class will do. I think the Animation class is handy for heavier stuff (like bones/skin morphs/etc.)

To use the tween class there are 3 basic steps:

1. include the class in your file (`<script src="js/Tween.js"></script>`)
2. add your tween for the event you need (`new TWEEN.Tween( cube.rotation ).to( {  y:Math.random()}, 1000 ).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();`)
3. update the tween in your render loop (`TWEEN.update();`)

You can have a have a look at the [cubes tween example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes_tween.html) for a start.

I've modified the default cube example to have the tween in:

[image: three.js cube tween]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js canvas - geometry - cube</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="../build/Three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Tween.js"></script>
        <script src="js/RequestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Stats.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var cube, plane;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            var rad90 = Math.PI * .5;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
                info.style.position = 'absolute';
                info.style.top = '10px';
                info.style.width = '100%';
                info.style.textAlign = 'center';
                info.innerHTML = 'click to tween';
                container.appendChild( info );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.y = 150;
                camera.position.z = 500;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // Cube

                var materials = [];

                for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {

                    materials.push( [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) ] );

                }

                cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1, materials ), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
                cube.position.y = 150;
                cube.overdraw = true;
                scene.add( cube );

                // Plane

                plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0 } ) );
                plane.rotation.x = - 90 * ( Math.PI / 180 );
                plane.overdraw = true;
                scene.add( plane );

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            }

            //

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();
                new TWEEN.Tween( cube.rotation ).to( {  y:  cube.rotation.y + rad90}, 1000 ).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();
                new TWEEN.Tween( plane.rotation ).to( { z:  plane.rotation.z + rad90}, 1000 ).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();

                console.log("click");
            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {
                TWEEN.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! We ended up using Tween.js and everything went great.

Comment: Am I mistaken or this will interpolate Euler angles (which is something you generally do *not* want to do)? What if you wanted to interpolate quaternions? In particular you generally want *spherical* interpolation between quaternions. Is there a simple way to adapt this code to achieve that? Or are we stuck at retrieveing the time passed since the start of the tween (if possible) and manually call `quaternion.slerp` with the right time?

Comment: @Bakuriu I haven't picked up issues regarding Euler rotation in the original question. I understood the issue was using the correct class to animate a property (rotation in this case) with the three.js library: mainly a syntax/api question more than a linear algebra one. You are right, Euler angles should to be avoided for rotations in 3D space in general, but in this simple example scenario, it doesn't really make a difference. You should be able to use the Tween class to animate `Object3D`'s `quaternion` property, just make sure you set `useQuaternion` to true before starting the tween

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! Struggled a while because I used `TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.EaseInOut` instead of `TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut`. Got an error *"TypeError: this._easingFunction is not a function"*. Maybe easing names have changed in a recent version.

Comment: @FrostyZ I know exactly what you mean. It's best to double check the reference for the version of the library you're using (worth noting this answer is now 6 years old). Depending on the motion you're after you might be able to get away with simple as simple as Quadratic, if so, it will also be slightly more efficient as it's not using `Math.sin()`/`Math.cos()` behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment & the perf tip. Well appreciated :)