# Rotation object on Web

Tags: javascript, html

I use three.js to load a simply 3d object from blender to web page. I want to rotate this object from rotation `vectorSTART` to `vectorEND` in time `TIME`(in this example only 'y' axis). I found a solution there [ThreeJS Rotation Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094971/threejs-rotation-animation) but there is an error `TypeError: _easingFunction is not a function` (when I click on screen). My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="Tween.js"></script>
        <script>
            var object;
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 5;
            camera.position.y = 0;
            camera.position.x = 0;
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
            loader.load("model(1).json", function ( obj ) {
                object = obj;
                scene.add( object );
                render();
                },
                function ( xhr ) {
                    console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
                },
                function ( xhr ) {
                    console.error( 'An error happened' );
                }
            );
            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            };
            function onDocumentMouseDown(){
                animate();
            }
            function animate(){
                //object.rotation.y += 10 *(Math.PI / 180);
                new TWEEN.Tween( object.rotation ).to( {  y:  object.rotation.y + (Math.PI * .18)}, 100 ).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();
                TWEEN.update();
                console.log("im here");
            }
            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why it doesn't work. However I dont have to use `TWEEN`, it would be great if you know any different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but IIRC Tween.JS's API requires comparable values in your "from" and "to" - try:

```
new TWEEN.Tween( object.rotation.y ).to( {object.rotation.y + (Math.PI * .18)}, 100 ).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.EaseOut).start();
```